# Child forms collections handling

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In case my ViewModel has some child property:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyFormViewModel Form {get;set;}
}
```

and I render a form for this property, I can then have the following ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyFormViewModel form)
{
   ...
}
```

and DefaultModelBinder fills form property (if ViewModel's property name equals to action parameter name).

But how should I name action parameter if MyViewModel contains `IList<MyFormViewModel>` which are rendered by index: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Forms[index])`?

Comment: Could you describe how it is in business? And how it will be in interface?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, for example there could be a list of items on the page, and I want to render editing form for each of them

Comment: Common solution is to edit and post items one by one. But if you want to post it as list, you need to read this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, I actually do not need to post the list, I want to be able to post one form of the list

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myViewModel = new MyViewModel()
            {
                Form = new MyFormViewModel {Name = "Header"},
                FormViewModels = new List<MyFormViewModel>()
                                     {
                                         new MyFormViewModel() {Name = "First"},
                                         new MyFormViewModel() {Name = "Secound"}
                                     }
            };

        return View(model: myViewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection, List<MyFormViewModel> FormViewModels, MyViewModel myView)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyFormViewModel Form { get; set; }
    public IList<MyFormViewModel> FormViewModels { get; set; } 
}

public class MyFormViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcChat.Models.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Form.Name)

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.FormViewModels.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FormViewModels[i])
    }
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>
}
```

The result should be this ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Je0.png ):

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

if you

> actually do not need to post the list, I want to be able to post one
>   form of the list

then just don't use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Forms[index])`.
Use

```
var element = x.Forms[index]
@Html.EditorFor(x => element)
```

your action parameter's name doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: The question is how I should call action parameter name (form, forms0, etc.) so that DefaultModelBinder recognizes it

Comment: Then the answer is "there's no that name". In case you use DefaultModelBinder and your GET parameters name is like Forms[0].Property1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done anything similar, but if it is possible (I don't know if it is), here you can find an old but good [starting point](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).
Hope to help.